# Loop through the first level in array and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I would like to have 10 variables named from day1 to day10, and for each of them the arrayOne[][] would increase only the first value before each Date function method, so for day1 it would be arrayOne[0][0], for day2 arrayTwo[1][0], day3 would be arrayThree[2][0] - so the second value would always would stay the same.

This code works but it seems extremely inefficient, is there a way to put it into a loop that would increase only the first "level" of array and assign it to the corresponding day?

```
var day1 = arrayOne[0][0].getDate() + "." +  arrayOne[0][0].getMonth() + "." +  arrayOne[0][0].getFullYear() + "." +
    " - " + arrayOne[0][6].getDate() + "." + arrayOne[0][6].getMonth() + "." +  arrayOne[0][6].getFullYear() + ".";

var day2 = arrayOne[1][0].getDate() + "." +  arrayOne[1][0].getMonth() + "." +  arrayOne[1][0].getFullYear() + "." +
    " - " + arrayOne[1][6].getDate() + "." +  arrayOne[1][6].getMonth() + "." +  arrayOne[1][6].getFullYear() + ".";
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - your question is not obvious as to what you are trying to achieve - for example `var day = []; for (var i=0;i<10;i++) { day[i] = arrayOne[i][0].getDate()....`

Comment: In this case what you can do is create a seperate function which takes `arrayOne` and `value` as parameters and return the output string which does the work. then you can call like `var day1 = myFunction(arrayOne,0)` and so on

Comment: Well using `forEach` or a simple `for loop` would do the trick here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a for loop:

```js
//generator function to test principle
var arrayOne = [];
a = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arrayOne[i] = [a, a, a, a, a, a, a];
}
//end

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
  //note how we use window to assign day variable with index.
  window["day" + (i + 1)] = arrayOne[i][0].getDate() + "." + arrayOne[i][0].getMonth() + "." + arrayOne[i][0].getFullYear() + "." +
    " - " + arrayOne[i][6].getDate() + "." + arrayOne[i][6].getMonth() + "." + arrayOne[i][6].getFullYear() + ".";

  
}

console.log(day2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, yes that's basically what I am trying to achieve...However I'm not familiar with this technique window["day" + (i + 1)], not sure how exactly that works, if you could explain shortly what happens here..? Thank you!

Comment: Quite simple once you know it. Javascript is object orientated. That means there is one master object `window` in the browser. You can use bracket notation to access properties on an object. So with `window[property]` you can access variables that are in the global scope but also assign new properties to the global scope.

Comment: Very interesting...So basically window ["day"] creates a variable day, great solution